# Socket.IO Client doesn't send to Server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Trying to achieve a simple thing. Sending data from Client to Server through Socket.IO.

However the problem is, I'm trying to use this through a webserver in this case "http://example.com/application.html".

The server app runs fine, and so does the Client without any errors. However, the server never receives the data sent from the client.

**Client (index.html):**

```
.. <body>

<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
  <input id="sentMessage" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io();

$('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#sentMessage').val());
    $('#sentMessage').val('');
    return false;
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});

</script>

</body> ..
```

**Server (app.js), runs through Node.js cmd:**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('A user disconnect');
    });

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        console.log('Message: ' + msg);
    });

});
```

In short, the result should be that on the page "http://example.com/application.html", I should be able to send a message to the server, which then sends the message out to other connected clients including myself, this is however not happening. It's really worth noticing that Localhost is not an option, since I need it to run on my domain. Everything runs on the same machine.

Comment: Does `A user connected` display in your server console?

Comment: Nope, nothing get's sent to the server.

Comment: Try adding `localStorage.debug='*';` before your `var socket = io();` and check your browser console for output when you load the page.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot connect to server.

```
var socket = io.connect('http://hereIsAdressToYourServer.com:8080');
```

Comment: `io.connect()` is called automatically by default.

Comment: Try to specify domain and port, as i write above.

Comment: Answer is consequence from that. Looks like his script simply connect to wrong place, and that is all.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue when running the app on heroku, where ports were handled automatically.
This is how I had to set the port.

`var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});`

This solved my issue. Maybe this is your problem too?